# Why is the shader changing in the final render?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders

i created multiple objects from a single piece and set its shader to a mix of glass and translucent when I view it in viewport, everything looks fine, it takes on the shader it was originally meant to take but as soon as i move to final render, one of the pieces 'loses' its shader and becomes opaque with a slit between it. also there is slight decolouration along the edges (i have marked) of a pre-made .stl designed in solidworks.
viewport screenshot -
[image: viewport :]

but in the final render, I got this ;

[image]

Comment: when you post pictures of one model that has an issue, make the two pictures from the same viewpoint please.

Comment: Make sure you disable any duplicates of your model from being rendered by toggling the camera icon in your Overlay Tab. Without looking at your scene, this looks like there's an older version of the model which is hidden in the viewport but isn't toggled off in the rendered view but without seeing the blend file it's difficult to know what's going wrong without more information or access to the file itself.